# Seaborn jointplot colour marginal plots separately

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to colour my marginal plots separately for each variable.

```py
d1 = np.random.normal(10,1,100)
d2 = np.random.gamma(1,2,100)
col1 = sns.color_palette()[0]
col2 = sns.color_palette()[1]
col3 = sns.color_palette()[2]

jp = sns.jointplot(d1, d2, kind="hex", annot_kws=dict(stat="r"), joint_kws=dict(bins='log'))
ax = jp.ax_joint
ax.plot(ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_ylim(), ls="--", c=".3", label="1:1")
```

Produces:
[image: Example Plot]

I want to colour each marginal plot separately. But when I assign arguments to the marginal axes they colour both marginal plots with the same arguments .

```py
jp = sns.jointplot(d1, d2, kind="hex", annot_kws=dict(stat="r"), joint_kws=dict(bins='log'), marginal_kws=dict(hist_kws= {'color': col2}))
ax = jp.ax_joint
ax.plot(ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_ylim(), ls="--", c=".3", label="1:1")
```

[image: Plot Colouring the Marginal Distributions]

I can colour the 'facecolors' but not the axes themselves. Any help very much appreciated!

```py
jp = sns.jointplot(d1, d2, kind="hex", annot_kws=dict(stat="r"), joint_kws=dict(bins='log'), marginal_kws=dict(hist_kws= {'color': col2}))
ax = jp.ax_joint
ax.plot(ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_ylim(), ls="--", c=".3", label="1:1")

# new code
jp.ax_marg_x.set_facecolor(col1)
jp.ax_marg_y.set_facecolor(col3)
```

[image: Coloring the facecolors individually]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by accessing the patches of two marginal plots and changing their face colors.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

# define data here

jp = sns.jointplot(d1, d2, kind="hex", annot_kws=dict(stat="r"), joint_kws=dict(bins='log'), color=col2)
ax = jp.ax_joint
ax.plot(ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_ylim(), ls="--", c=".3", label="1:1")

for patch in jp.ax_marg_x.patches:
    patch.set_facecolor(col1)

for patch in jp.ax_marg_y.patches:
    patch.set_facecolor(col3)
```

[image]

Comment: And how do I get the annotation to show? I have added: annot_kws=dict(stat="r") but it doesn't show up anywhere on the plot?

Comment: Sorry I realise new question but just thought about that! Awesome answer

Comment: @TommyLees: I would recommend to post a new question on that as it could be of potential importance for many. In the mean time, I will work on the answer and let you know asap.

Comment: thank you very much I did just that here -  https://stackoverflow.com/q/55285704/9940782

Comment: @TommyLees: By annotation, you mean the equation of the best fit straight line, right?

Comment: I mean the values of whatever stat I pass to `annot_kws=dict(stat="r")`. Here it is just the Pearson's R correlation but it could also be the equation of the best fit line.

Comment: @TommyLees: Did you try the solution I commented on your other post?